# Install SQL Loader on Amazon ec2 server to remotely load into Oracle RDS instance

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sql-loader

I have an Amazon RDS instance running and use an ec2 server as the tunnel to connect from my local machine

I have successfully tested connections from this ec2 server to the instance with JDBC

I have a lot of data I'm pulling from a DB2 instance into CSVs that I wish to load into the Oracle RDS instance with SQL Loader

However I've yet to find a way to install SQL Loader on the ec2 instance. While I have found similar questions/answers, they seem to be relevant only to Oracle => Oracle RDS as opposed to generic CSV => Oracle RDS

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you use external tables instead of SQLoader? Effect is quite similar.

Comment: I am specifically wanting to test the performance of SQLoader, but thank you for the pointer

Comment: If you're tunnelling through ec2 doesn't that include SQL\*Net; if so can't you run SQL\*Loader on your local machine? Are the CSV files only on ec2, or do you have them locally and copy them to ec2 to load?